# Route override doubles records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'd like to override a default path of an Spree/Rails extension.

The extension spree_contact_us defines default route in it's config/routes.rb this way:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts,
    :controller => 'contact_us/contacts',
    :only       => [:new, :create]
  match 'contact-us' => 'contact_us/contacts#new', :as => :contact_us
end
```

In the routes table there is just **one** record for route named *contact-us*:

```
contact_us  /contact-us(.:format)  spree/contact_us/contacts#new
```

If I pass following override in main application's config/routes.rb to `routes.prepend` method

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
  match 'napiste-nam' => 'contact_us/contacts#new', :as => :contact_us
end
```

`rake routes` displays routes to a new named path *twice*, when passed to `routes.append` even *three times*:

```
contact_us  /napiste-nam(.:format)  spree/contact_us/contacts#new
contact_us  /napiste-nam(.:format)  spree/contact_us/contacts#new
```

Can anybody explain this behaviour ?

Comment: You are prepending or adding in front of you are not actually replacing anything. Why not just edit the original route? I don't use spree so I am not sure if this is a possibility.

Comment: @engineersmnky By overriding wasn't meant replacing literally but changing path to the same controller, which will take the precedence. I'm expecting just one record with the new path will be pushed at the top of routing table.

Comment: so you are trying to have multiple paths to the same controller and method?

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, as a way to change default urls. It does not matter if there are more to the same controller as only the first one matched takes an effect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you will be creating an ambiguous named route `:contact_us` which when referenced by `contact_us_path` will return the path for the last entry in routes because you are redefining it.

The duplication does seem strange but I have not looked at how spree handles these things. 
In order to avoid this you could rename the secondary route such as

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.append do
  match 'napiste-nam' => 'contact_us/contacts#new', :as => :contact_us_czech
end
```

This should create 2 routes in which you could use `contact_us_path` and `contact_us_czech_path` which will both lead to the same place. then create a method to determine which to use.

Or just add the new route directly into the spree routing tables as (PROBABLY NOT VALID DUE TO CALL TO `routes_reloader` in Spree Core.

```
match 'napiste-nam' => 'contact_us/contacts#new', :as => :contact_us
match 'contact_us' => 'contact_us/contacts#new', :as => :contact_us
```

Just remember that this means that `contact_us_path` with always reference the second route.

**Edit**
It seems Spree builds the default routes and then reloads them after initializing as is stated in the code

```
  # We need to reload the routes here due to how Spree sets them up.
  # The different facets of Spree (backend, frontend, etc.) append/prepend
  # routes to Core *after* Core has been loaded.
  #
  # So we wait until after initialization is complete to do one final reload.
  # This then makes the appended/prepended routes available to the application.
  config.after_initialize do
    Rails.application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end
```

I believe this is causing the named route `:contact_us` to be routed to it's defined route meaning that you defined it as `contact_us` and then redefined it as `napiste-nam` and since a variable can have only 1 value it held on to the second one on `reload!`. Due to this fact I am not sure you can do this directly through Spree.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I'm now investigating the issue by your advices. Later let know about the results and probably accepting your answer.

Comment: Just found it's an already known bug in Spree [#11895](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11895) . Upvoted your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw
```

instead of

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend
```

solved the routes duplication problem for me.